# Save current data from UITableView

Tags: iphone, uitableview

Trying to figure out how data storage from UITableViews is ment to work. What is good practices when saving a UITableView data on e.g. viewDidDisappear.

Do I have to update an array with every changes made while working in the view, or can I collect all current values form the table on exit view?

Can someone point me in the right direction?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

First, on when to save the data, I would suggest you save your data in this method instead of viewDidDisappear:.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
```

Second, there are a bunch of ways to store data in iPhone applications, such as plist or sqlite3 database.

Answer (score 0):

You are thinking about the problem the wrong way around. The UITableView only displays the data currently on screen. Its not a place to ever collect data from (other than user interaction which you should collect when they interact - didSelectRowAtIndexPath). Spend some time reading up on Model View Controller. The UITableView data should have COME from a model - the view should simply display it - so there is nothing to collect.

Comment: Yes, I know. My table contains UITextFields, so the value will change. Therefore I need to collect data from UITableViewCell. If I understand you correctly, the way to do this is to update the dataSource array/dictionary on every action, and not grab them all on exit/disappear?

Comment: absolutely! Grab at the end of each interaction. If you need to provide a transactional commit (OK / cancel button) that scopes all the changes then use that to merge your temporary model back into the main - Core Data provides great support for this sort of thing with save: reset: and rollback:

Comment: come to think of it I've not seen an app that collects data in a UITableView other than didPress/didSelect type actions - text entry normally comes from a child screen. Are you going to have issues if the fields are at the bottom of the list and the keyboard renders over the top ?

Comment: Thanks! I'll collect on each interaction then. When keyboard renders I change the view frame, and scroll the text field to bottom position. Works great.

Comment: I see you are relatively new here. You should go back over all your old questions and accept one of the answers (hint!) :-)